# How do I finish this method to add a value to a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, insert, nodes

So I'm new to linked lists in Java.  I need to finish a method that adds an item to the linked list.  Can anyone help me complete the if statement so that the method works correctly? Thanks for you help.

```
void insert(int item)
  {
//find location to insert
Node current = head;
Node prev = null;
boolean located = false;

while(!located && current != null)//correct location found
{ 
  //I need to add a condition to the if statement below. What is the condition
    if(item
    current = current.link;//assign the next node from head to current node
  }

  //create new node and
  //refer to the correct location in list 
  Node newNode = new Node(item, current);

  //set link to refer to new node
  if (current == head)
  {
    head = newNode;//new node to head
  }
  else
  {
   //place new node after previous LINK reference not the node itself
   prev.link = newNode; 
  }    
}
```

Comment: I meant "your" help :)

Comment: Then you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the list is supposed to be sorted? If not then the simplest thing to do is to add the new item to the start of the list:

```
head = new Node(item, head);
```

If, however, it needs to be sorted then you need to find the first item that is larger than the item you are inserting:

```
while (!located && current != null) { 
    if (item < current.item) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.link;
    } else {
        located = true;
    }
}

Node newNode = new Node(item, current);
if (current == head) {
    head = newNode;
} else {
    prev.link = newNode; 
}
```

This code is looking for the point at which the new item needs to be inserted. At that point `prev` and `current` reference the nodes before and after the new node. If you get to the end of the list then `current` is null.